# SOLR result are not too accurate

Tags: solr, sitecore, fieldtype

I'm trying to improve my SOLR scheme to search in chinese field. 
In my index I have document with name_t_zh value AB考試課程3
Scheme for field type looks like this:

```
<fieldType name="text_general_zh" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

For that field I'm doing query:

```
name_t_zh:(AB考試課程3)
```

Problem is with the query which SOLR makes:

```
 "parsedquery":"name_t_zh:ab name_t_zh:考試 name_t_zh:課程 name_t_zh:3"
```

And in result I'm getting more not accurate result which contains number 1 and the rest is totally different or part of Chinese character. I want get one document with exactly the same name or the same text with other character at the end or beginning.

Comment: "I want get one document with exactly the same name or the same text with other character at the end or beginning." - does this mean that you want to get documents that contain this substring somewhere, and not parse them as separate words? In that case - use a pure string field, and query it with wildcards (`name_s_zh:*AB考試課程3*`)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is it gonna handle Chinese and other characters?

Comment: Yes. They're pure UTF codepoints here, since you're not performing any analysis or tokenization on them.